# Unknown special variable used in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I can't understand what does **%%** mean in the following code. could anyone expalin a little bit? seems that there is a perl special hash variable referenced by %%, but after some google
search, still don't find a good answer.so drop the question here.

```
$execOut =   `ps -ef --cols 180 | grep nsproc`;
$execOut =~ s/%%//g;
```

Comment: .. Are you sure it's not just matching the string "%%"?

Answer (score 8):

Nothing special to it. It erases all instances of pairs of `%`. `%` isn't special in Perl string and regex literals. Only scalars and arrays can be interpolated.

```
>perl -E"$_ = 'abc%%def%%ghi'; s/%%//g; say;"
abcdefghi
```

Comment: I was afraid to put this as an answer, I thought I had missed yet another deep secret of Perl regexes... :P

Comment: Well, if you want learn something new about regexs, or at least s///, check out `s///r` which makes `say 'abc%%def%%ghi' =~ s/%%//gr;` equivalent to the code in my answer.